# Artifactory + 18.04 artifactoryManage.sh does not create PID file

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory, ubuntu-18.04

I am using Artifactory with ubuntu 18.04 (pre-release).  All appears to work fine however the artifactoryManager.sh script does not properly create the ARTIFACTORY_PID file like 16.04 does.   I have done some minor debugging but I can not determine why the pid files is not created by systemd.

If I invoke the /opt/artifactory/bin/artifactoryManager.sh start  manually through sudo via the command line it works fine.  I suspect some kind of 18.04 environment or systemd change or some dash/bash issue.   Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I revered to 16.04 for our deployment.

Comment: Same problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by setting a bigger timeout, this can be done increasing the value for the variable START_TMO (defaults to 60)

There are multiple ways of doing It, but here is how I did It:

the official script installService.sh leaves the configuration here:

/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory

in that place you have a file with the name default, the last line could be used to define the timeout: uncomment It and set a bigger value, for example

```
# Timeout waiting for artifactory to start
START_TMO=120
```